# adding a new item to a jquery sortable not being picked up by refresh

Tags: jquery

I'm sorting a list of objects, some of which are regular objects, and some of which are containers of other objects.

Sortable with a handle is working fine, except when I add a new object to the container, it is not recognized after refresh.

I have the following HTML:

```
<button>add another option</button>
<div class="con">
    <div class="ui-state-highlight"><span class="handle">handle</span> Item 1</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight"><span class="handle">handle</span> Item 2</div>
    <div class="ui-state-highlight"><span class="handle">handle</span> Item 3</div>
    <div class="subthing">
        <span class="handle">handle</span>
        <div>    <span class="handle">subhandle</span> subitem</div>
        <div>    <span class="handle">subhandle</span> subitem</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and script:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight"><span class="handle">handle</span> newthing</div>');
    x.appendTo('.con')
    $(".con").sortable('refresh')
});

var container = $(".con");
container.sortable({
    handle: container.children().children(".handle")
});​
```

#### [The Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLrVF/14/)

As seen in the above code if you add a new item, it can't be sorted with the rest of the elements. I know if I say the handle property is `.handle`, that it will do that, but I don't want the sub-handles to be part of the sortable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you need is:

```
container.sortable({
  handle: '> .handle'
});​
```

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/hQsjD/

It is the > sign that only captures the immediate .handle child.

It is important the handle argument be a string selector and not actual elements because those will not get refreshed when you call refresh.

Comment: what if the handle is not the immediate child of the item being sorted. like if i'm sorting fieldsets and the handle is in the legend

Comment: Then you can do something like: '> .something > .another_something > .etc > .handle'    The point is to be exact about where in the hierarchy .handle appears so sub handles will be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Here you go. You weren't using handle correctly:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight"><span class="handle">handle</span> newthing</div>');
    x.appendTo('.con');
    $(".con").sortable("refresh");
});

var container = $(".con");
container.sortable({
    handle: ".handle"
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dLrVF/18/)

Comment: in this case the subhandles will drag their parent container, which I would like to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing worked for me but this:

Instead of:

```
$(".selector").sortable('refresh');
```

I've put this:

```
$(".selector").trigger("sortupdate");
```

Answer (score -1):

This seems to have solved it: [edit](http://jsfiddle.net/4XjYk/)

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var x = $('<div class="ui-state-highlight"><span class="handle">handle</span> newthing</div>');

    //My Edits
    x.appendTo('.con')
    var container = $(".con");
    container.sortable({
        handle: container.children().children(".handle")
    });
});

    var container = $(".con");
container.sortable({
    handle: container.children().children(".handle")
});
```